# Negative year value in date type column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

We have a table in Oracle with a date type column proto_date. When I run the following query :-

`Select EXTRACT(YEAR from proto_date) from tablename;`

I get result as -3832. Can Oracle store such date values where year is negative?

Comment: please show the full date value then.

Comment: When i run following query :- ```SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column, 'dd-mon-yyyy AD') FROM table```.   I get 07-jun-3832 BC. This answers my question. The dates was stored as BC. That is why we are getting negative year. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Oracle store such date values where year is negative?

Oracle dates can range in year from 4712 BC to 9999 AD.  Extracting the year from a BC date will yield a negative number.